# Observable return type issue

Tags: angular

What happens if HTTP request should return array of object and I set return type just object not array of object.

Here I'm setting return type `Student` not `Student[]`, what will happen? Can any one explain that?

```
searchStudent(term: string):Observable<**Student**> 
{
    if(term.trim() === '')return of([] as any);

    return this.http.get<Student>(this.StudentsUrl+'/?name='+term)
}
```

Why is it working correctly if I try to loop through result even it's not **array of Student**?

Answer (score 0):

In `angular` and `typescript` the validations will be only done at the compile time. They are useful to get suggestions and errors from the editors.

When you loop through the result, what data type have you declared under subscription?? Is it `any`??: If its not then you should be getting some error when you `ng serve`.

```
this.myService.searchStudent(term).subscribe((data: any) => {
    // your loop here..
})
```

Once the application has compiled successfully, you can actually get any value into any variable type during runtime. 
For example, if you have a variable of type `number`, it can receive a value of type `String` or `Array` and you won't get to know about it if you have not done any `Number` specific operation on that variable.

Comment: i don't declate any data type to subscribe ? it's mean the default is any ??

Comment: .subscribe(student => this.students = student) here is the subscribe and when i bot for loop on this.students its work successfully why ?

Comment: @aliamer: what is the type of `this.students`? Where are you actually looping?

Comment: Student object not array of student object

Comment: @aliamer How and where do you loop?

Comment: <li *ngFor="let student of students">
          <a>{{student.name}}</a>
        </li>

Comment: @aliamer: Oh, then rendering in `HTML` is again runtime I believe. If you do something like: `this.students = 1` (removing the type). You will still not get any errors during compilation but when you open your browser, you will see errors in your console. So, in your case it actually finds an `ìterable` and loops without errors.

Comment: @aliamer: And no, if you haven't given a type specifically, it will asume the type as the return type of the method you are subscribing to..

Comment: @aliamer: `iterable`: something on which you can `iterate` i.e. `loop` over. Which is an `array` in your case

Comment: what mean ( ìterable ) ?

Comment: @aliamer: I just explained that in the previous comment. Its something on which you can loop over. `ngFor` supports `Arrays` to loop over.